# How to handle response in the jsp from a servlet for a multipart file upload?

Tags: java, servlets, response, multipartform-data

There are two web applications. One is a client and other one is the provider. The provider is hosting a servlet to process a multipart file upload request. The client will upload the file to the provider servlet. The bottleneck is how to send a response back to the client. The client need to process according to the response send back by the provider. We cannot forward the request and response to a servlet/jsp because both the applications are in different servers. Then how to trap the response in the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write to the response body.

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.getWriter().write("OK");
```

You can even write XML or JSON so that parsing the response by the "client server" is easier.

---

**Update** as per the comment, the question is apparently poorly formulated and your *actual* problem lies elsewhere. It's not the response handling which is the problem, but the request handling. With JS/Ajax you cannot fire multipart/form-data requests. You've got to use Flash or a POST form in a hidden HTML iframe. You can find plethora of examples [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+file+upload). I personally recommend [jQuery Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).

Comment: Thanks BalusC..But how to handle the response in the client side. In AJAX we can wait for the response in the readyState==4 and we can process accordingly in the jsp. But in case of AJAX we cannot send the multipart file upload. So I need a similar functionality like readyState in AJAX which will wait for the response from the provider.